# Partitioning External Hard Drive

Tags: external-hard-drive

Is there a way to partition a External Hard drive ?

I have a WD 500GB external hard drive with USB interface

Sorry forgot to tell about os:
using windows XP:

Comment: What OS are you using?

Comment: OS - Windows XP

Answer (score 0):

Yep! Gparted works GREAT! http://gparted.sourceforge.net/